# Convert a list of dictionary in python into unique list of individual dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to convert a list of dictionary represented as

```
[{'primary': 'shsong'}, {'primary': 'hdsouza'}, {'primary': 'ncarol'}, {'primary': 'ncarol', 'secondary': 'ncarroll'}, {'primary': 'ncarol', 'secondary': 'jhsja'}, {'primary': 'ncarol', 'secondary': 'djkwhfew'}, {'primary': 'ncarol', 'secondary': 'jkadhbjkldaf'}]
```

into a list of unique individual dictionaries :

```
[{'primary': 'shsong'}, {'primary': 'hdsouza'}, {'primary': 'ncarol'}, {'secondary': 'ncarroll'},  {'secondary': 'jhsja'}, {'secondary': 'djkwhfew'}, {'secondary': 'jkadhbjkldaf'}]
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? Please go through, [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
def get_all_dicts(dictlist):
  for d in dictlist:
    yield from d.items()

dict_list = [dict(zip([k], [v])) for k, v in set(get_all_dicts(data))]
```

Output -

```
[{'primary': 'ncarol'},
 {'secondary': 'djkwhfew'},
 {'secondary': 'ncarroll'},
 {'primary': 'shsong'},
 {'secondary': 'jhsja'},
 {'secondary': 'jkadhbjkldaf'},
 {'primary': 'hdsouza'}]
```